# shared memory vector<string>, allocating strings with 8 byte alignment in 32 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, 32bit-64bit, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I'm using boost shared memory to share data between 32bit and 64bit processes.

Under 64bit everything works fine, but under 32bit I get a compilation error whenever I need to allocate new elements to a `vector<string>`. `string` alone works without problems, also no problems with `vector<uint32_t>`. It's really only the `vector<string>` that seems to be at odds:

> error C2718: 'boost::container::basic_string,MDSDATA::char_allocator>': actual parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned

The shared memory is defined with alignment of `uint64_t` for 32bit-64bit compatibility:

```
namespace bipc = boost::interprocess;
namespace bc = boost::container;
typedef bipc::basic_managed_windows_shared_memory
     <  char
     ,  bipc::rbtree_best_fit
        <
            bipc::mutex_family,
            bipc::offset_ptr<void, int32_t, uint64_t>
        >
     ,  bipc::iset_index
     >                                                          managed_shm_type;

typedef bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bipc::allocator<void, segment_manager_t> > void_allocator;
typedef void_allocator::rebind<char>::other                     char_allocator;
typedef bc::basic_string
        <
            char,
            std::char_traits<char>,
            char_allocator
        >                                                       char_string;
typedef void_allocator::rebind<char_string>::other              string_allocator;
typedef bc::vector<char_string, string_allocator>               string_vector;
```

I only get the compilation error whenever I add code that reallocates elements in the vector like `emplace_back()`, `resize()`, `insert()` etc. Like in the following piece of code:

```
string_vector & list(segment->getListvectorReference());
list.clear();                 // this works fine
list.emplace_back("hello");   // this fails
list.resize(20);              // this fails too
```

An important note is the following: If I remove the code that causes the compilation error in the 32bit build, I am able to create new elements of the vector from the 64bit side and read them correctly from 32bit. It's just the opposite direction (32bit allocating the strings) that doesn't work.

---

**Update:**

Following [this post](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-341) and the [respective patch](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/pull/281/commits/4d82640fe19601679b732e9896704028d1e7f5bf), I came to the assumption that this might be an issue with the Microsoft Compiler in conjunction with *boost*. I'm using *Visual Studio 2015 Express Update 3*. This is also supported by the error message itself that points to the file `boost/move/detail/type_traits.hpp`. I have the gut-feel that there may be an easy patch available to fix this in boost.

Unfortunately, my knowledge is not sufficient to come up with a patch that would fix this issue in boost. However, I'll give credit to anybody that is able to provide a solution.

For the time being I can live with this bug since I realized that my software will never allocate these strings from the 32bit code.

---

**Update 2:**
There was [a fix applied](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/pull/33) in boost 1.64 that has some relation to this issue.

Comment: Try: `typedef __declspec(align(8)) void_allocator::rebind<char_string>::other string_allocator;`

Comment: @Rotem, unfortunately this does not work. I've tried it with both, the `string_allocator` and the `char_allocator` as well as with the `vector_string`. All variants produce the same error still while compiling fine  on 64bit.

Comment: Right, according to Microsoft documentation [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxe76d9e.aspx), you should actually avoid using `__declspec(align())` for `typedef`s

Comment: Are you using declaration like: `typedef struct __declspec(align(32)) AlignedStruct`, or is it deep inside BOOST implementation?

Comment: No, all of these `__declspec(align(xx))` stuff is inside boost. (If there is...) In my code, I have not a single `__declspec` declaration since I'm trying to be as crossplatform capable as possible.